# Thread safety in Glassfish 3

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish

We have been using Glassfish 3 without many problems until recently. It seems two different threads accessed a non-shared data structure and modified it beyond recognition. This happens quite frequently when there are lots of hits on the server. My question is: can I assume each request to Glassfish is executed in a separate thread? Also, do I need to choose thread-safe data structures like StringBuffer instead of StringWriter, Vector instead of ArrayList, etc. I haven't found relevant answers in the search engines. I would appreciate if you can solve my quandary.

Than you

Comment: Yes, you must assume that requests happen concurrently in different threads. But blindly using classes like `Vector` (which is also pretty much deprecated) will not solve your problem. Concurrency is far more difficult. You'll find the answers you'll need in books like http://www.amazon.de/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Comment: Sorry, can't say you answered my question. I am looking for an explanation for why parallel threads corrupted a non-shared data structure. Should I be using thread-safe data structures? Thx

Comment: I can't answer your question without knowing details of the problem. If you have a concrete case: post a concrete question with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - threads don't corrupt non-shared data and thread safe data structures solve only certain cases.

Comment: Please provide some code showing the key aspects of your non-shared data structures and how it is used.

Comment: We are using Glassfish 3 application server that in theory has to execute each request in its own thread. I don't think that is what is happening in practice. The code is trivial. No fancy gimmicks other than a bunch of StringWriter/PrintWriter classes. Thanks